# Split view radare2 print heap

Tags: radare2, heap

I recently start to use radare2 and I have a question
How can I print info about the heap with dmhb dmhf etc. while debugging ?
I would like to have the heap informations on the right and the disassembly view on the left but I don't know how to do it .

When I launch these commands it prints below the disassembly view...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `|` or `=` in *Visual Mode* to split horizontally and vertically respectively.

Open your file in debug mode and go to Visual Mode by pressing `V`, then press `p` until you reach the assembly view:

```
$ r2 -d program
[0xf7799b30]> V
```

Then press `|` and you'll be able to configure `cmd.cprompt`. Write the command that you wish to see in the right pane of the screen.

Alternatively you can configure it using `e cmd.cprompt=<your_command>` or `e cmd.vprompt=<your_command>` from the terminal.

Comment: You are absolutely welcome! :)